# apt-get fails Debian

Tags: dns, debian, portforwarding, apt-get

I have a Linux server that is running Debian squeeze, I can not run `apt-get update` on it. I get errors like these:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz
Unable to connect to 10.197.3.5:3142:
```

I can successfully `ping ftp.us.debian.org` ,but the **ip address** that it shows is different than the **ip address** shown with the unable to connect message.

I assumed this was an issue with **DNS** translation, so I changed my **DNS server** to `google's 8.8.8.8 server`
Running `dig google.com`

shows that the **DNS server** is in fact the **google** server I specified. 
I'm stumped. It may be of note that I am forwarding **port 22** and **port 80** to my **router** so my teammates can `ssh` and view the webpage associated with this server. I don't think this is the issue since this occurs even when I stop the forwarding.

Comment: I think there could be some problem with your `sourcs.list` and please share the version you are using.

Comment: Do you have a proxy defined?  Could possibly be in `/etc/apt/conf` or `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf` if the conf file doesn't exist.

Comment: It was the proxy issue! This server was set up by another company, and I didn't realize they set up a proxy

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the original holder of this server set up a proxy in /etc/apt/apt.conf that wasn't working, (I don't know why this was)
I remove this line form that file
Acquire::http::Proxy "PROXYIP/apt-cacher/";

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed similar issue applying one comment about your issue:

**My environment is:**

```
Linux debianlpi 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1 (2016-12-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**The issue that I got, was:**

```
root@debianlpi:~# apt-get install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  vim-runtime
Suggested packages:
  ctags vim-doc vim-scripts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  vim vim-runtime
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,999 kB of archives.
After this operation, 28.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  vim-runtime vim
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
0% [Connecting to idcproxy.compabc.com (432.1.2.20)]
```

**It was fixed removing line in /etc/apt/apt.conf:**

```
root@debianlpi:~# cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
#Acquire::http::Proxy "http://idcproxy.compabc.com:80";
```